# Should it be Boost/s, Make/s in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number

I can't figure this one out:

> Secrets That *Boost* Productivity and *Make* Meetings Effective

Should it be *Boost* or *Boosts* / *Make* or *Makes* here? I'm leaning towards Boost/Make, but I'm not sure.

(I tried to google both versions and got 300.000 hits either way)

Comment: *Secrets* is plural, so it takes the plural form of the verbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence "Secrets that boost productivity and and make meetings effective." is grammatically correct.

> Secrets that Boost Productivity
>
> Secrets that Make Meetings effective

Since *secrets* is plural, so we will see the plural form(*Boost* and *Make*) of both verbs.

This sentence is also correct though:

> The secret that boosts productivity and makes meetings productivity.

Since *secret* is singular, verbs will take singular form(*Boosts* and *Makes*).

Answer (score 0):

Secrets boost, a secret boosts.

It's similar to more common grammatical structures: it makes, they make.

Answer (score 0):

*Secrets* is plural, so boost and make is used with it.

If it would be *Secret*, which is singular, it would have used boosts and makes.